# Highcharts chart with risk color background

Tags: charts, highcharts, risk-analysis

I would like to create a chart that has dynamic elliptical areas as background.
The background should visualize the risk and can be static but needs to render to different sizes of the chart of course.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this with highcharts?

[image: Example of what I would like to display]

Comment: Well, I suggest to use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to render such paths (closed path with fill of course). To calculate proper values for paths use [`x/yAxis.toPixels()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels).

Comment: Would it also be possible with a radialGradient? Otherwise, do you have an example for the mentioned path technique?

Comment: As I can see, you achieved that by using radial gradient, nice job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I solved the problem with a radial bBackground color.

```
chart : {
    type: 'spline',
    renderTo: chartData,
    zoomType: 'x',
    plotBackgroundColor: Highcharts.svg ? {
        radialGradient: {
            cx: 1.0,
            cy: 0.0,
            r: 1.5
        },
        stops: [
            [0.0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)'],
            [0.5, 'rgba(255, 193, 86, 1.0)'],
            [1.0, 'rgba(44, 160, 44, 1.0)']
        ]
    } : null
},
```

The radialGradient starts at 1.0, 0.0 (x, y) which is in the top right corner of the plot area.
I added three color gradient stops: red, yellow, green.

Hope this helps someone having the same problem. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this solution does not work for IE8. :-/ Does anyone have a good idea?